# Execute PHP function from AJAX button

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, function, elementor

Using wordpress plugin "Code Snippets" - How could I take a php function like the one below and turn it into an Ajax button inside of elementor?

Essentially... i'd really like to know how I can take any PHP function and execute it from an Ajax button.

Thanks so much for your help! Clearly I have no idea what I'm taking about.

Function:

```
add_action( 'init', 'woocommerce_clear_cart_url' );
function woocommerce_clear_cart_url() {
    if ( isset( $_GET['clear-cart'] ) ) {
        global $woocommerce;
        $woocommerce->cart->empty_cart();
    }
}
```

Comment: Google WordPress Ajax and find a few thousand articles.

Comment: Thank you for your reply... I have for the last few days... Yes! Thousands of articles but they're very poorly explained and It's very confusing. People tend to assume you already know quite a lot... but I don't haha.

Comment: I doubt they're bad articles, it's that you aren't a programmer. This website isn't a place where you just get free code snippets to solve your problem. Maybe you might consider hiring a professional?

Comment: I apologise, I didn't mean to waste your time... I just thought maybe someone could help me out. I know quite a lot of HTML and CSS so I try to share with others what I can also. But I understand... I won't post here again.

Comment: Rob. You can post here, but put in some effort before you do.  I would suggest reading [ask] and [mre] first. If you want to write code, then learn about what you're doing, then when you get stuck, come here for help refining your code. This site is not a "learn how to write code" site, it's a "help with your code" site.

Answer (score 0):

you can put the php function inside a php file and do a ajax call to execute the php script and you can use the response data like below:

```
$.ajax({
        url: "functionfile.php",
        type: "post",
        data: values ,
        success: function (response) {

           // You will get response from your PHP page (what you echo or print)
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
           console.log(textStatus, errorThrown);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to checkout the code here I created the admin hook to clear the cart using ajax

```
<?php

// Ajax Action 
add_action('wp_ajax_customAjax', 'customAjax');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_customAjax', 'customAjax');
function customAjax() {
    global $woocommerce;
    $woocommerce->cart->empty_cart();
    echo json_encode(array('msg' => 'done'));
    exit;
}

// Ajax JavaScript Call
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'clearCart' );
function clearCart()
{
    ?>
    <script>
    function customAjax() {
        var my_repeater_ajax_url = '<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>';
        jQuery.post(
            my_repeater_ajax_url, {
                'action': 'customAjax',
            },
            function (json) {
                if(json['msg'] == 'done')
                {
                    location.reload();
                }
            },
            'json'
        );
    }
    </script>
    <?php
}
```

Comment: Thanks Mahesh for your reply... Super appreciate it. How would I trigger this from a button in Elementor or a basic HTML Button?

Comment: You can now customAjax() use this in your javascript button click event or set href to javascript:customAjax() or onclick to customAjax().